# Trying to Understand Angular Error (v4.2.4)

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

I'm using Angular 4.2.4 and Angular CLI version 1.4.9.  I typed in an example from the first edition of Angular 2 Development w/ TypeScript (chap 5) and got this error.  Can anyone help me understand what this kind of error might mean?  The book's author wasn't helpful.

```
    `Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
No provider for ControlContainer ("[ERROR ->]<form name="searchForm" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="productTitle">P"): ng:///AppModule/SearchComponent.html@0:0
    at syntaxError (compiler.es5.js:1694)
    at TemplateParser.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.TemplateParser.parse (compiler.es5.js:12791)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.es5.js:26994)
    at compiler.es5.js:26913
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.es5.js:26913)
    at compiler.es5.js:26800
    at Object.then (compiler.es5.js:1683)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.es5.js:26799)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.es5.js:26728)`
```

Comment: check [No provider for ControlContainer when building a simple form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37537157/2435473)

Comment: That book is old. The form APIs were all changed several times (and they still suck)